# Identify a row to format text

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a macro to format the text boxes (i.e. the properties of a textbox like fontname,font size,alignment) present in a slide in a *ppt*, by taking the properties as input from *excel* file using **VBA**.

Here is the screenshot of input *Excel* file :
[image]

Basically My Approach was to identify the  row no of *shapeid* of each text box,so that once I get the row no,I can pass the range `FRowno:0Rowno` range as input eg(F4:O4)

However I'm not able to uniquely identify the row number with *shapeid* since there are rows with same shape id,which are present in other slide numbers as well

What approach/other Shape Property can be included in the excel sheet, in this scenario, to uniquely identify a row in this regard?

Comment: Not tested, but did you try `Shape.id`

Comment: Yes Shape.id is the one which is not unique in the column

Comment: You could the slide name and text box name in the `Tag` element. Then change your textbox name in the sheet to something more meaning full. You can then use the combination of the 2 to uniquely identify the row. i.e. you have shape IDs set to **9** for `Slide 2`. Change the text name from `a Text Box` to maybe `TextBox9-12` and change the other one to `TextBox9-20`. Set `Tag` element for the textbox to something like `Slide2 Textbox9-12`. You can use this to uniquely identify your format

Comment: Thanks @Zac for the suggestion combining with Slide no has worked !!